# hiding .php address bar object not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a simple problem, i tried to remove .php on the address bar using this code below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

and it works but eventually it keeps on displaying "OBJECT NOT FOUND" how do i fix this problem?

Comment: I have a feeling that the “OBJECT NOT FOUND” is coming from your code, which was presumably written not expecting rewrites to be in effect. Look around in your code to see if you can figure out where “OBJECT NOT FOUND” is coming from.

Comment: i think there is something to do with the **<a href></a>** in which that page is referring to but I dont have any idea to fix it

Comment: Well there's not enough information here for us to have any idea of how to fix it either.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Example: Your page is: www.yoursite.com/yourpage.php . Now you can access the same page without ".php".

**ALSO**

You can try to remove [R] permanent redirect (to remove your error), and mantain the extension in rule.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: but how do i to do something like this? www.site.com/pages/?id=213

Comment: You're welcome! OK. So, do you want to get the ID of the post to search it on database and show on your site?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is remove the `.php` extension from your URLs, just use `Options +MultiViews`, no need for the rewrites.